Movie about possession
The thing is I watched this movie a long time ago and all I can remember is that it's about a demon or the devil that has possessed a man for a long time and now that the man's body is old and in a wheelchair, the demon/devil is trying to pass into another/ younger body. I can't recall clearly but it might be in french. It was set in the late 19th century early 20th.
A very prominent thing was that when possessing a body this demon does this sort of counting with his fingers. With a single hand he goes touching his thumb to his fingers one by one and back.
I'm not sure about the release date but it has to be in this range 1988-2007.
If anybody has any idea what movie I'm talking about I'd be very grateful for any answer or suggestion. I've been looking for it for many years now.

The movie Hypnotic AKA Close Your Eyes AKA Dr Sleep (2002), starring Shirley Henderson and Goran Visnjic is about moving your own consciousness into another body even if the trailer dose not allude to much to this.
"With a single hand he goes touching his thumb to his fingers one by one and back" -- this is what stood out in your question as this features in this movie and you can see this bit in this tralier. 
There is an old man in this and maybe from memory an even older one in a wheelchair but I think its an older lady we may see at the end.
Close Your Eyes

OMG YES !!! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!! I LOVE YOU <3 AGES AGES I'VE BEEN LOOKING FOR THIS MOVIE

No worries. I also love this film.
